# Bringing a wild Ghost-type to 1 HP in Sword and Shield

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

In Pokémon Shield, I would like to hunt for many Sableye. If I were doing this in any other game, I would use Foresight/Odor Sleuth and then False Swipe. However, in SwSh, Foresight and Odor Sleuth have been removed. This method no longer works.

With such strong Pokémon at this stage in the game, it won't be easy to dwindle the HP with weak moves. Furthermore, there is always the off-chance a crit will kill it.

If there a consistent method in SwSh for hunting Ghost-types? Are weak moves my only option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can accomplish this in Sword/Shield by using [Pangoro](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pangoro_(Pok%C3%A9mon)). Pangoro can get the move False Swipe and has [Scrappy](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Scrappy_(Ability)) as its hidden ability.

The description for Scrappy states:

> Scrappy causes Ghost-type Pokémon to be hit by damage-dealing Normal- and Fighting-type moves inflicted by the user.

Hidden abilities can only be obtain via raids (or trading/breeding), and Pangoro can be found in Dens 10, 63, 69, 88

Comment: I did some further research and a Max Raid Pangoro with a hidden ability is only available in Den B of Dusty Bowl and a part of the rare pool (the dens with the purple beam). That gives me a 5% chance to encounter one. Additionally, I need to capture it. So my best bet here is to breed.

Comment: Upon even more research, I found that the only two Pokémon with the non-hidden ability Scrappy, are Kangaskan and Miltank, two Pokémon that are _always_ female, so they can't pass on their ability via breeding. That 5% for a Pangoro is looking pretty good now.

Comment: @Diriector_Doc Oof, I didn't realize it was only a 5% spawn in the Dusty Bowl. There is always the option of getting one via Pokemon Home, if you choose to go that route. Who knows, you might get lucky :)

Comment: @Diriector_Doc You can't pass hidden abilities between different species anyway. The *only* way to breed a Scrappy Pancham is to already have a Scrappy Pancham/Pangoro.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery my mistake. For some reason, I thought that the ability of the egg Pokémon would be the same as the male Pokémon's, that is if the male's ability was one of the egg Pokémon's available 3.

Answer (score 9):

It's not ideal, due to needing two Pokemon to pull off, but: **an Inteleon or Hatterene + a False Swipe user can allow you to consistently hunt ghost-types**.

Inteleon (as well as a handful of other water types, most of them more difficult to obtain than the lizard) can learn [Soak](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Soak_(move)), a move that changes the target's type to pure water. Hatterene learns [Magic Powder](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Magic_Powder_(move)), the psychic equivalent. Using this strategy, you can lead with your 'type-altering' move user, use Soak/Magic Powder, and then once the Pokemon you are hunting is no longer a ghost-type, switch to your False Swipe user and attack with the now-effective move.

It takes three turns, rather than the two needed when Foresight was still usable, but if you can't find someone to trade you the Pokemon you need it's likely to end up being faster than having to hunt for a Pokemon with a spawn rate like HA Pangoro's.

(As a note, I don't actually *recommend* Hatterene for this; Magic Powder won't work on Sableye at all due to its part-dark typing. And even for ghosts she can actually manage to hit with Magic Powder, sending out a lead with the weakness to the type you're trying to hunt isn't a great plan. In the interest of completeness, though, I'm including both.)

Comment: Adding to this, some of the Soak users like Inteleon, Wishiwashi, and Pelipper can use U-turn to do some chip damage after using Soak whilst switching out simultaneously. The extra damage could effectively save one turn of using False Swipe, netting back some of the lost time from using two Pokemon in a battle. Just as long as you don't OHKO with U-turn. An Eject Button can also work, but it seems like a waste of a consumable item to me.